# Is JSF 1.2 fully supported on JBoss EAP 7

Tags: jsf-1.2, jboss-eap-7

I'm currently migrating a JSF 1.2 + Seam 2.2 application to JBoss EAP 7, but I am reading some contradicting articles from Redhat.

There is this [migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/migration_guide/application_migration_changes#migrate_jsf_code_changes) from Redhat claiming

> JBoss EAP 7 includes JSF 2.2 and no longer supports the JSF 1.2 API. If your application uses JSF 1.2, you must rewrite it to use JSF 2.2.

But there also is [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2773121) Redhat knowledgebase article explaining how to use JSF 1.2 with EAP 7 (which I currently use)

My current problem is, that my values from the view are not properly bound to the Model and I don't know if it is due to some missing support or otherwise.

The same code runs on EAP 6 just fine.

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is not packaged with Jars to support JSF 1.2 so the Multi-JSF feature should be used to create an alternative jsf-impl for JSF 1.2. The jsf-impl for JSF 1.2 is a simulation of the "1.2" JSF slot in EAP 6.4.x.The solution mentioned in this article once implemented should work for you have you followed it?Are you getting any exception?

Comment: yes followed the article to enable jsf 1.2. the page itself renders fine, but just the attribute bindings don't work. I can see for example the values in the post request sent to the server, but the bean will stay empty.